# Allowing user to restart bluetooth on linux

Tags: linux, permissions, bluetooth

I'm using bluetooth on linux to access internet via dialup from my Nokia S60 phone. I've gotten the connection to work just fine, but there's still one recurring problem:

Some Nokia S60 phones, mine included, have the habit of changing the channel they offer their Dial-Up Networking service on. One day it's 2, the next day it may be switched to 9. For linux, this means that each time it happens I have to go edit the `/etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf` to contain the right channel and then use "`/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`" to reboot the bluetooth service.

I've created a script to do all this for me, and granted edit rights to the `rfcomm.conf` - but restarting the bluetooth service still needs super-user rights. I'd rather not have to type my password every time the phone feels a need to juggle channels, so:

**How do I grant the user access to restart the bluetooth service?** Preferably without breaking too much of my access control - so granting the user full root-level access is not a solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
Cmnd_Alias BT=/etc/init.d/bluetooth
username ALL=NOPASSWD: BT
```

to your /etc/sudoers file. Don't forget to change *username* though :)

This will allow you to run `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` without entering the password but sudo will still ask for it when you run it with any other application.